# Duvidas relacionadas a recursão

Tags: java, recursão, árvore-binária

Boa tarde. Estou desenvolvendo metodos recursvios que atuam sobre uma arvore binária de pesquisa, porém estou tendo grandes dificuldades na recursão.

Por exemplo, o método abaixo deveria retornar a altura da árvore:

```
public int altura(){
      return altura(root,0);
  }

  private int altura(Node n, int cont){
      if(n==null) return 0;
      cont += 1;
      if(n.left != null)
          return altura(n.left, cont);
      if(n.right != null)
          return altura(n.right, cont);
      return cont;
  }
```

porém, ele retorna somente a altura dos nodos ao lado esquerdo da raiz, e quando os do lado direito tem uma altura maior ele continua somente verificando o lado esquerdo.
O meu problema com a recursão é que eu não sei como faco para fazer ela seguir para ambos os lados, direito e esquerdo. Por exemplo, se eu estou na raiz e ela tem dois filhos, eu quero que o método seja aplicado tanto para a esquerda quanto para a direita, porém no método abaixo ele só aplica para a esquerda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta você chamar o método recursivo duas vezes. Pois a altura da árvore será um mais a altura da sua maior sub-árvore, então é necessário avaliar ambos os lados antes de se determinar a altura. Um exemplo seria:

```
  private int altura(Node n){
      if(n==null) return 0;
      int alturaE = altura(n.left);
      int alturaD = altura(n.right);
      if ( alturaE > alturaD )
          return alturaE + 1;
      else
          return alturaD + 1;
  }
```

Esse é um caso em que não faz muito sentido se usar um acumulador (esse parâmetro adicional `cont` que você está usando) uma vez que não é possível usar recursão de cauda a menos que se passe uma estrutura de dados "pilha" como parâmetro adicional (posso dar um exemplo se achar necessário).

Comment: Recursividade é uma coisa de doido, eu crio um metodo que chama ele mesmo dentro do proprio corpo, é bem louco de imaginar. kkk

Comment: Era isso mesmo! muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public int altura()
    {
        return altura(raiz, 0);
    }

    private int altura(No n, int cont)
    {
        // Imagine we have the tree below:
        /*
         *               R
         *              / \
         *             A   B
         *            / \      
         *           /   \  
         *          C     D
         *
         */

        // Now imagine a the situation in during the execution.
        // We've reached the C, coming from A. So:
        // 1. the execution of altura( nodeA, 1) will not
        //   make exit W; but will do exit Y.
        // 2. the next execution of altura( nodeC, 2) will
        //         do exit 1.
        //
        // Observe that, in step 1, after returning, we *will not*
        // continue the execution for altura( nodeA, 1) - it already
        // returned!
        //
        if( n == null )             // Exit W
            return 0;
        cont += 1;

        if( n.left != null )        // Exit X
            return altura(n.left, cont);

        if( n.right != null )       // Exit Y
            return altura(n.right, cont);

        return cont;                // Exit Z
    }
```

Comment: Como esta é uma comunidade da língua portuguesa do Stack Overflow, seria interessante que os comentários estivessem também em Português. Considere [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/99093/edit) a sua resposta e traduzir os comentários para Português. Seja bem-vindo :)